# Python iterator over string using keyword in

Tags: python

I recently came across some python code I don't understand completely.

```
s = "abcdef"
x = "bde"
it = iter(s)
print all(c in it for c in x)
```

I understand that this code checks if x is a subsequence of s. Can someone explain or point me towards an article that explains what's exactly happening at `c in it`. What is calling the next method of iterator `it`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s good to start with reading the documentation for the built-in function [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).

That means that `c in it for c in x` is a [“generator expression”](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/): it produces values. The values it produces are of the boolean expression `c in it` (see the [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in)) for all characters `c` in string `x`.

Here, the `in` operator is responsible for advancing the iterator. Note, however, that the True result is probably lucky. The iterator `it` can advance only once and because `x = "bde"` contains the letters in the same sequence as they appear in `s = "abcdef"`, the whole expression works out to the expected result True. Reverse `x = "edb"` and the expression is False because the iterator is exhausted.

Comment: _"because all letters of x are also letters of s"_ - i.e `x` is a subset of `s`.

Comment: Judging by the question's use of the word "subsequence", it sounds like the code is *supposed* to return false for `x = "edb"` and `s = "abcdef"`.

Comment: @user2357112, while the op’s _commentary_ uses the term “subsequence” the code does _not_ implement a subsequence, and `"bde"` is certainly not a subsequence (i.e. substring) of `"abcdef"`.

Comment: @Jens: ...but it does, doesn't it? At least by the definition used in contexts like the [longest increasing subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence), where a subsequence doesn't have to be contiguous, as opposed to a [substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring), which does have to be contiguous.

Comment: @user2357112 in that case, I agree.